# QComboBox - Drag and Drop

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

how to use the Drag-and-Drop (in Qt; C++) mechanisms for QComboBox. That is I want to drag a QComboBox and drop it somewhere else in its parent. I want its items in its popup list to remain exactly the same. In other words, the whole QComboBox is the QWidget onto which the Drag and Drop are applied.

My problem here is as follows: when there is a mouse press event, how to distinguish between (1) open popup list and (2) start a drag. Several solutions: 1. On the QComboBox, define one region for the “popup list” and one region for the drag. 2. Put the QComboBox in a larger Qwidget.
Any help is welcome
JP

Comment: Show your attempts (some code)

Comment: If your widget receives a mouse move event that is outside the widget's boundaries, it means that user is trying to drag the widget because this can only be possible if user clicked on widget and dragged mouse outside of the widget, which doesn't happen if user simply wants to use the widget. Reimplement `mouseMoveEvent` (or install an event filter) and check event coordinates. Note that previous mouse press event needs to be accepted by the widget.